# Reflection / C# typing errors when publishing an F# class implementing an interface

Tags: interface, f#, binding

I have an interface written in C#, but when implementing it in F#, I noticed some oddities.

- The F# class has to be cast to the interface before C# can consume it
- After casting, WPF can't read it's properties (Bindings failed and SNOOP was unable to reflect on it)
- I can wrap the object in C# code and everything works fine.

**the interface**

```
public interface IInterpret {
  public string Name {get;}
  public IEnumberable<Project> Interpret(string text);
}
```

**The F# Class**

```
type Interpreter()=
  interface IInterpret with
    member x.Name = "FParsec Based"
    member x.Interpret(str) = Seq.empty
```

**The code below fails to compile**
The error is about Interpreter not implementing IInterpert

```
public ViewModel(){
  IInterpret i = new FSharpLib.Interperter(); 
}
```

**This is my current workaround**

```
public class MyProxy: IInterpret{
    private IInterpret _cover;

    public MyProxy()        {
        _cover = new FSharpLib.Interperter() as IInterpret;
    }
    public string Name { get { return _cover.Name; } }
    public IEnumerable<Project> Interpret(string text){
        return _cover.Interpret(text);
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with my F# class def, or is the proxy needed?  I'm using the current VS2010 f#, not an out of band drop.

Comment: FYI: new is optional on F# constructors, and is idiomatically used only with types implementing IDisposable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# implements all interfaces explicitly.  This means you must explicitly cast to the interface type.

I don't know a ton about WPF binding to explicit interfaces, but see if these

http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2008/09/generic-binding-in-wpf-through-explicit.html

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/92a2a3ba-74a6-4c79-9c75-f42d232a4dbf

help? (I just found them Bing-ing for "wpf binding explicit interfaces".)

(Another alternative may be to do something like

```
type Interpreter()= 
    member x.Name = "FParsec Based" 
    member x.Interpret(str:string) = Seq.empty 
    interface IInterpret with 
        member x.Name = x.Name
        member x.Interpret(str) = x.Interpret(str)
```

where you "explicitly implement the interface implicitly", if you pardon the confusing terminology.)

Comment: Thanks for the understanding.  I missed the explicit implementation bit and the impact that can have on binding.