# Can't access Dispose method in F# class

Tags: f#, dispose

I have created a class in F# that implements the IDisposable interface.   The class is cleaned up correctly and the use keyword is able to access the Dispose method.  I have a second use case where I need to explicitly call the Dispose method and am unable to in the example below.  It appears as though the Dipose method isn't available in the class.

```
open System

type Foo() = class
    do
        ()

    interface IDisposable with
        member x.Dispose() =
            printfn "Disposing"

end

let test() =
    // This usage is ok, and correctly runs Dispose()
    use f = new Foo()


    let f2 = new Foo()
    // The Dispose method isn't available and this code is not valid
    // "The field , constructor or member Dispose is not defined."
    f2.Dispose()

test()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflection / C# typing errors when publishing an F# class implementing an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120004/reflection-c-sharp-typing-errors-when-publishing-an-f-class-implementing-an-i)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implementing an interface in an F# class is more similar to the *explicit interface implementation* in C#, which means that the methods of the interface do not become public classes of the method. To call them, you need to cast the class to the interface (which cannot fail).

This means that, to call `Dispose` you need to write:

```
(f2 :> IDisposable).Dispose()
```

In practice, this is not needed very often, because the `use` keyword ensures that `Dispose` is called automatically when the value goes out of scope, so I would write:

```
let test() =
  use f2 = new Foo()
  f2.DoSomething()
```

Here, `f2` gets disposed when the `test` function returns.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  I have instances inside another class that need to be cleaned up when the outer class closes, so I couldn't use use.  This works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Tomas has it right. FYI, you can implement a Dispose() function on your type for ease of use:

```
member x.Dispose() = (x :> IDisposable).Dispose()
```

That's *outside* the implementation of `IDisposable`. Then you can just write `f2.Dispose()`.